# "Em vez de" ou "Ao invés de"?

Tags: gramática

Quando usar *"Em vez de"* ou *"Ao invés de"*?

As duas expressões existem na língua portuguesa e me parecem corretas, só não sei o momento de usá-las.

Comment: Quando usar "Em vez de" em vez de "Ao invés de"? :D

Answer (score 10):

[**Em vez de:**](http://www.aulete.com.br/vez) significa no lugar de, emprega-se quando o sentido é de troca, ou seja, substituição.

Exemplos:

> Em vez de viajar de ônibus, fui de carro;
>   Em vez de ir ao cinema, fui ao teatro;
>   Em vez de refrigerante pedimos suco.

[**Ao invés de:**](http://www.aulete.com.br/inv%C3%A9s) deve ser empregada **apenas** quanto existe a ideia de oposição, de situações contrarias.

Exemplos:

> Ao invés de sorrir ele chora;
>   O dolar ao invés de cair, sempre sobe.

No entanto, `em vez de`, pode ser empregada nas duas situações. Em caso de dúvida use `em vez de`. Já `ao invés de` somente no sentido de oposição, situações contrarias.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de adicionar links. Podes sempre tirar se não gostares.

Comment: Legal, boa complementação.

Comment: Apesar dessa distinção semântica, ao menos no Brasil, o comum é usar "ao invés de" para qualquer situação. Eu tento fazer essa distinção na minha fala, mas poucas pessoas percebem a diferença na hora de ouvir, e na hora de falar tendem a usar o "ao invés de" sem considerar a semântica original da expressão.

Answer (score 3):

[Daqui](http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/noticias/qual-e-o-certo-ao-inves-de-ou-em-vez-de): "Ao invés de" expressa contrariedade, já "em vez de" expressa substituição.

Answer (score 3):

A palavra [vez](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vez) traz consigo o significado de "ocasião, turno", assim quando se é a *vez* de algo é o momento desse algo ser usado ou o momento em que ele deveria ser usado.

Dessa forma, **em vez de** significa que algo será usado no lugar de outra coisa de modo a indicar uma substituição ou alternativa.

> Vou usar um lápis vermelho em vez de um lápis azul.
>
> Em vez de sair com os amigos, eu deveria estudar.
>
> Tomei chá em vez de tomar café.

Por outro lado, [invés](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/inv%C3%A9s) tem o significado de "avesso, lado oposto", como exemplo têm-se que direita é o '*invés*' de esquerda, entrar de sair, subir de descer.

Portanto, **ao invés de** significa "ao contrário de" indicando situações inversas, opostas.

> Arrastou-se feito uma lesma ao invés de vir correndo.
>
> Ao invés de calar-se, continuou berrando asneiras.
>
> Eu, ao invés de você, conheço o meu lugar.

Brincando, podemos perguntar:
**Quando usar "Ao invés de" em vez de "Em vez de"?**